# C# modify list of string without iterating

Tags: c#, string, foreach, ienumerable

I have a List which is returned to me from a 3rd party. Each string in the list ends in "mph" and I would like to remove the "mph".  The obvious answer is to foreach over the list but I didn't know if there was a more efficient way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: one way or other, you have to perform a iteration!

Answer (score 5):

in a word, no. *Something* has to pass over the list in order to modify it. A `for` loop is probably the most efficient way though not necessarily the most concise

Answer (score 4):

You have to iterate over the list to touch each item and make a change.

The easiest way to do this is via linq:

```
  var originallist = new List<string> { "50mph", "35mph", "100mph" };
  var newlist = list.Select(s => s.Substring(0, s.Length - 3));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ instead of a `foreach` loop:

```
list.Select( s => s.Substring(0, s.Length - 3) )
```

Comment: -1 Wrong function ;P. ForEach doesn't exist and not close to what its called unfortunately. Ok i undid the -1

Comment: It certainly does exist: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx, but I was just thinking of the wrong function. Fixed.

Comment: I'm sorry. Wow I learned something new. Its kind of strange they have that in List but not in linq. It also bothered me there was a Find in list but the equivalent in linq is first which kind of messed me up. +1

Comment: Yes, if strings weren't immutable that might be more efficient for many types of operations. But see this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @AndrewMao: IMHO, less code to write is also a kind of "efficiency" :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use LINQ for that purpose. Something like this might works :

```
var noMph = theList.Select(p => p.Replace("mph", "").ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this isn't more "efficient" than a `for` loop. In fact, it's probably less efficient.

Comment: well, at least it is more efficient in terms of the amount of code you have to write :)

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Answer : You Can't

---

One way or another you have to perform a iteration.

it may be :

```
foreach
for
List.ForEach
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can write

```
mylist.Select(s=>s.Substring(0, s.Length-3));//Can add .ToList() here
```

But that is using a loop. You don't have to write the foreach at least :)

Comment: @AndrewMao: Hahahaha oh crap, fixed :). -edit- funny enough this always gets me in real code until i run and see the mistake on screen

Comment: Also fix the `substring` to `Substring` :)

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();

mylist.ForEach((item)=>
  {
    item=item.Replace("mph",""); 
    newlist.Add(item);
  });
```